# Asymptotic Distribution of Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression

Given an integer $n$ and let $1\leq m\leq n$ be such that $n$ and $m$ are coprimes define 
$$
\mathcal{N_{n,m}}:=\text{the set of primes $p$ such that $p\equiv{m}\hspace{0.1cm}\mathrm{mod}(n)$}.
$$
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all primes. I seem to recall that the following result is true:
$$
\varphi(n)^{-1}=\lim_{k\to\infty}{\frac{|\mathcal{N_{n,m}}\cap\{1,2,\ldots,k\}|}{|\mathcal{P}\cap\{1,2,\ldots,k\}|}}.
$$
where $\varphi$ is the [Euler's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

My question is two fold:

- Does anyone have a reference for the previous fact? I was unsuccesful finding it.
- Are there finer results along these lines? Second order results?

Thanks!

Comment: This is due to Dirichlet. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: @wood: Clearly not, it implies the PNT.

Comment: @Charles, in principle one could prove that the primes in one residue class are $1/\phi(n)$ of all the primes without knowing the asymptotics of either counting function, thus, without PNT, no? I agree that Dirichlet did not do this. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good way to find the result you mentioned is to search for Dirichlet's (prime number) theorem; while Dirichlet only proved the infinitude of the set in question, nowadays one will frequently find the more precise assertion you mentioned when this result is discussed.

A more common way to state it is that the number of primes congruent to $m$ modulo $n$ smaller than $x$ is asymptotically equal to $\varphi(n)^{-1} x/log (x) $  (assuming coprimeness as you did), which in combination with the prime number theorem implies what you are looking for.

There are a variety of results related to finer aspects of this problem;
key words e.g. Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem or Siegel-Walfiz Theorem.

See for example the wikipedia article on Dirichlet's theorem [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) which also links to the keywords I mentioned for a quick overview.

Other than that as Gerry Myerson said any typical book on Analytic Number Theory will contain something on this subject (how much depends of course on the book).

Comment: The $x/\log x$ result can't be Dirichlet's, as it would imply the prime number theorem, which came about 60 years after Dirichlet's work. 

Comment: +1 for the pointer to Siegel-Walfisz. 

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment but what about the second question? Are there more precise results?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, of course you are right I was imprecise (and will change this). And, sorry for the wrong spelling of your name. 

Comment: Yes, see 2nd paragraph of unknown (google)'s answer for keywords.

Comment: Thank you for the references! and I'm sorry if it was too elementary my area is not number theory.

Comment: As I edited in between it is now the third one.

Comment: @Gabriel H. Tucci, you are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

It's just the prime number theorem for primes in arithmetic progression, no? Should be in any analytic number theory text that does the prime number theorem.